# What is the best practice to search in SQL Server with large data for a string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I wanted to know that what may be the best practice to search for keywords or sentence in SQL Server.

Suppose I have a table say products with name, description and keywords. I have a search function in my website where the user may type in anything (sentence or single word).

I query the product table columns using like clause and shortlist the list to rows containing the search criteria.

To reduce the response time in case if the volume of data in product table is large, I add a pagination query of 10.

My current query

```
select *
from 
    (select 
         srno as productid, name +' '+ descriptions +' '+ keywords as search
     from 
         ProductDetails) PD 
where 
    PD.search LIKE '%bed%' 
    OR PD.search LIKE '%sheets%'
```

Here I have combined the three columns namely name,descriptions and keywords and I am searching for "bed sheets" in my product table

Is the above explained scenario a good practice?

Table Structure

ProductDetails example
srno|Name|Description|keywords
1|Floral Bed Sheets|..some text..|bed sheets 
2|Square Pillow Covers|.. some text..|pillow covers square

Is it proper to place keywords in a separate column or should I create a new table for keywords.
If I have to create a new table for keywords, how to modify the above query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not the right way. You will face performance issue when the table grows now it may run fine. Try implementing **FULL TEXT INDEX**.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. actually i am using a shared server and it does not allow me to set up full text search for sql server. Is it possible to achieve full text search capability manually, what I mean is creating table of keyword index. Can you pls guide me? Thanks.